# Headless Chrome Puppeteer Select Item from a 'non' select Element

Tags: google-chrome, select, headless, puppeteer

I am try to set the zipcode to 'NY - New York' via Puppeteer's page.select() on the USPS.com website's zip code search https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupAction_input

The issue is that the underlying tag is not a select element, its a span tag.  The following code does not work.

```
await page.select("#sStateList > div.select-current > span", "NY - New York");
```

Answer (score 0):

USPS.com is apparently using Dojo toolkit, however main **select** element name/id is: "**sState**" you can just change **sState** value and form will work on submit.